# How to use Images as buttons in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am developing a recipe application,It is a salad recipe application, i want add each salad items images one by one in a scroll view,when a user clicks an image of a salad item then i want to display its recipe details.How can i implement this on my application, can i use pictures as buttons?? Can anybody help??

I just tried setting images as buttons.Is it the right way??

I created an xml file called images_button in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/first" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/first_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/first_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/first" />
</selector>
```

And my main xml file is

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_image"
    />
```

Comment: Change Button to ImageButton in your xml file.  and where from you getting recipe detail ?

Comment: I think it's a list of recipes and if you click one of this user can see recipe details. Why you didn't use `listView`? There you can add in each item `imageView`and short description, after make each item clickable with `setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly use `ImageButton` like this inside your layout xml file.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button_image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can set an OnClickListener on every Android View, but I think you should rather look at a ListView with custom item layout and use an OnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageButton`. It behaves just like a normal button, only it is capable of displaying images

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/some_image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can usepicture as button using ImageView and setting onclick listener.

Alternatively You can also create a Listview or grid view with list item being an image and using onitemclick listener.

Also as other suggested image button.

I think ImageView will fulfill your requirement.